# Clear Files from Parse Cache

Tags: ios, caching, parse-platform, pffile

I have an app which is using parse, and it is downloading a caching a lot of files.

The app size on disk is getting rather large.

Is there any safe way currently to clear items from the cache?

According to https://www.parse.com/questions/pffilecache-refresh-and-pffile-versioning it's not possible, but that's a year old and I'm hoping something has changed here.

Thanks!

Comment: Anyone from parse.com able to comment here?

Comment: I am still having the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.parseplatform.org/ios/guide/#caching-queries), it is now possible to delete the cache.

To delete cache of a **specific query** use:

```
query.clearCachedResult()
```

To delete **complete cache** use:

```
PFQuery.clearAllCachedResults()
```

Comment: Parse Lives On! 8 years later...